# Ajax response text

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to parse a ajax response text, I am getting a whole form from an ajax responsetext, but how to append this form to my existing page just under the button, this ajax call happens on this button click.

Tried adding this response text using appendchild, but did not work, can any one please help me out with this.
is my approach right in this context, if so how can I get this form from the response text on to my page.

Comment: Please post some sample code, and a sample of the response you're getting

Comment: so i am trying to do:   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText); - I see the form html code in the response text, I want this form to be added on my web page.

Answer (score 1):

simplest way is to create a an empty placeholder and then place response text into it on ajax success

HTML

```
<div id="ajxresult"></div>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById("ajxresult").innerHTML = ajaxresponse;
```

Comment: What does jquery have to do with it?

Comment: You don't always have a console.

Comment: @Rab Nawaz: Thank you very much, I didn't know that we can add the whole form with innerhtml.

Comment: Is the HTML getting built from data on the server-side or are you stashing HTML directly in the database? Because that combined with dumping directly into innerHTML would be kind of awful. But yes, given the question, this is the most direct answer.